# Cumulative total based off of two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sapb1

So I am looking to get an extra column into my query that calculates a cumulative balance based off of the credit/debit columns.

My query looks like this so far:

```
 SELECT T1.[RefDate], T1.[TransId], T1.[BaseRef], T1.[LineMemo], T3.[Dscription], T1.[Debit], T1.[Credit], T4.[AcctName]
    FROM OJDT T0
    right JOIN JDT1 T1 ON T0.TransId = T1.TransId
    left JOIN OPCH T2 ON T0.TransId = T2.TransId
    left JOIN PCH1 T3 ON T3.DocEntry = T2.DocEntry
    left JOIN OACT T4 ON T1.Account = T4.AcctCode
    WHERE T4.[AcctCode] = [%0] AND
    T1.[RefDate] BETWEEN [%1] AND [%2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use windowed `SUM`:

```
SELECT T1.[RefDate], T1.[TransId], T1.[BaseRef], T1.[LineMemo], T3.[Dscription], 
    T1.[Debit], T1.[Credit], T4.[AcctName],
    SUM(ISNULL(Debit,0)+ISNULL(Credit,0)) OVER(PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY refDate)
FROM OJDT T0
right JOIN JDT1 T1 ON T0.TransId = T1.TransId
left JOIN OPCH T2 ON T0.TransId = T2.TransId
left JOIN PCH1 T3 ON T3.DocEntry = T2.DocEntry
left JOIN OACT T4 ON T1.Account = T4.AcctCode
WHERE T4.[AcctCode] = [%0] AND
    T1.[RefDate] BETWEEN [%1] AND [%2];
```

If `Debit` column contains positive values you need to prefix it with `-`.

Comment: Hi, This works to a point. It displays the column fine, but it just seems to be replicating the values from either the debit/credit column and doesn't seem to be actually adding them up. Could this be down to me incorrectly using the `Partition By`? I'm not 100% on how to use it. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Documentation around OVER: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461(v=SQL.110).aspx

You'll probably find example C to be the most useful though it looks like you don't want to PARTITION, you want to use RANGE.

you'll want something like this for your calculated column:

```
 SUM(ISNULL(Debit,0)+ISNULL(Credit,0)) 
       OVER(RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS RunningTotal
```

This will result in a query something like:

```
SELECT T1.[RefDate], T1.[TransId], T1.[BaseRef], T1.[LineMemo], T3.[Dscription], T1.[Debit], T1.[Credit], T4.[AcctName],
    SUM(ISNULL(Debit,0)+ISNULL(Credit,0)) 
               OVER(RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS RunningTotal
            FROM OJDT T0
            right JOIN JDT1 T1 ON T0.TransId = T1.TransId
            left JOIN OPCH T2 ON T0.TransId = T2.TransId
            left JOIN PCH1 T3 ON T3.DocEntry = T2.DocEntry
            left JOIN OACT T4 ON T1.Account = T4.AcctCode
            WHERE T4.[AcctCode] = [%0] AND
            T1.[RefDate] BETWEEN [%1] AND [%2]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a subquery or a common table expression (CTE) to calculate the cumulative balance.

I have done it using CTE

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        T1.[RefDate],
        T1.[TransId],
        T1.[BaseRef],
        T1.[LineMemo],
        T3.[Dscription],
        T1.[Debit],
        T1.[Credit],
        T4.[AcctName],
        SUM(T1.[Credit] - T1.[Debit]) OVER (ORDER BY T1.[RefDate]) AS CumulativeBalance
    FROM
        OJDT T0
        RIGHT JOIN JDT1 T1 ON T0.TransId = T1.TransId
        LEFT JOIN OPCH T2 ON T0.TransId = T2.TransId
        LEFT JOIN PCH1 T3 ON T3.DocEntry = T2.DocEntry
        LEFT JOIN OACT T4 ON T1.Account = T4.AcctCode
    WHERE
        T4.[AcctCode] = [%0]
        AND T1.[RefDate] BETWEEN [%1] AND [%2]
) SELECT * FROM CTE;
```

Please have a try and comment it still facing the same?